# Error with json VirusTotal API call in python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I need to retrieve the result of VirusTotal scans already performed, providing the hash of the files, without sending the file again.
You can find the documentation of the API [here](https://www.virustotal.com/it/documentation/public-api/).

I basically need to send a json of this format: `{"resource": "hash", "apikey": api}`.
I'm using **requests**, it's very useful and it should handle json even without using the **json** or **simplejson** module.

if I send a request like this it works:

```
r = requests.post(url, data = {"resource": "dbbe9c39df7c355f970e3a9636fbac04" , "apikey": "myapikey"}
print(r.json())
```

but I have many hashes so I need to generate the json programmatically instead of hardcoding it in the program.

First I tried using a dictionary:
the **api** key doesn't change so I put the assignment out of the loop, instead for the **hash** I loop through a **list** of hashes called **md5**.

```
params = {}
params["apikey"] = api
for hash in md5:
    params["resource"] = hash
```

I get a dictionary for every loop that I pass to **requests** for the API call.
The dictionary representing the json is of this format:

```
{'apikey': myapikey', 'resource': 'hash'}
```

The documentation shows `resource` as first element of the json, instead in my generated dictionary I get the `apikey` first, anyway if they implement correctly the json standard, order shouldn't matter. Anyway that isn't a valid json format because it contains single quotes, it should contain double quotes. I wanted to avoid using another module but I tried using `json` or `simplejson` module for converting the dictionary in a valid json (with double quotes) and it works apparently. I know that requests also has a `json =` paramenter where you can pass a dictionary and it should encode it as json for you but I'm not sure it worked. Otherwise you can just use the `data =` paramenter and assign the json to it when you make the request.

If I make a request like this:

```
params = {}
params["apikey"] = api
for hash in md5:
    params["resource"] = hash
    json_params = json.dumps(params)
    r = requests.post(url, data = json_params)
    print(r.json())
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Fabio/PycharmProjects/dfir/requests-try-prova.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(r.json())
  File "C:\Users\Fabio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 812, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Fabio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\simplejson\__init__.py", line 516, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Fabio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Fabio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

line 15 in my code is represented by `print(r.json())`

if I `print(r.text())` instead it says `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

---

Then I tried a slightly different approach still using the `json` module without passing a pre-defined dictionary:

```
for hash in md5:
    r = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps({"resource": hash, "apikey": api}))
    print(r.json())
```

where `hash` and `api` are 2 strings.

I still get the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Fabio/PycharmProjects/dfir/requests-try-prova.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(r.json())
  File "C:\Users\Fabio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 812, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Fabio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\simplejson\__init__.py", line 516, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Fabio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Fabio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

From the error it seems the problem is in getting or decoding the json response, but I wonder if the problem is that the request isn't sent correctly in the first place.
If instead of printing the json response I do `print(r.status_code())` I get a **403** status.

It's a typical HTTP status that means "`Forbidden`" and also the Virus Total API documentation says: `If you try to perform calls to functions for which you do not have the required privileges an HTTP Error 403 Forbidden is raised`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that I used a variable called `hash` and it could cause an issue because it can be mistaken with a method by the Python interpreter so I renamed it to `file_hash`. Then instead of using `r.json` I used `r.text` for getting the response as text and then I passed it as a argument to the function `json.loads`, I stored the value in a variable called `response`. `response` is a dictionary and it contains keys and values wrapped by **single quotes** rather than double quotes like in a valid json, so I had to take this into account when I wanted to extract the values from the response. I don't get any error now, code runs. The only issue is that after a few retrieved jsons (precisely 4), I got the same error as before: `simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`
This is probably because I wasn't getting a json response anymore. If you are asking why, it's because the public API supports only up to **4 requests/minute**, so I had to implement a sleep function in order to pause the report retrieval for 1 minute every 4 requests. (I was aware of this since the beginning). I implemented several other checks and functions in my code, anyway I show you the basic code that works:

```
    for file_hash in md5:
        params = {"apikey": api, "resource": file_hash}
        r = requests.post(url, data=params)
        report = json.loads(r.text)
        print(report)
```